# Use field in last item to filter the list view

Tags: 2007, list-view, filter

I have a list which is updated about once a week with 50-100 new items through the use of Spreadsheet view and pasting from Excel. My problem is that I need to find what date when the list was last updated and then filter a list view based on that date so that only the latest batch is listed.

The site is on SP2007, however we're upgrading to SP2010 soon so if it's not possible on SP2007 I could move to SP2010 instead. I have SPD2007 and some basic programming knowledge in Java, but I would prefer a solution without coding.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1. Create a view where you filter for the value of the last modified field, and compare it to the value of [today-7].
2. Create a view with calculated column with filter =[Modified]+7, and its return type is DateTime, which will returns the documents changed within the last 7 days

more information on creating view and filter is here http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/10/advanced-sharepoint-view-and-filters/

Comment: Just to clarify: In the context of this question I think 7 days should be used :)

Comment: yes,I do agree, Edited the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, however I mentioned "about once a week", the list may be updated more often or more seldom, for instance during hollidays it might be two weeks between the updates.